# How to remove labels from search page in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, device

I want to remove the labels look like that image.

[image]

How to remove this. Please help me.......

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using simple listbox.
just put image and textblock inside your listbox itemtemplete.

here is the code example.

```
                      <ListBox x:Name="lst">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Margin="10" Source="{Binding image}" Width="60" Height="60"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Comment: No, it's displayed in my windows phone device.

Answer (score 0):

you cant remove jumplist property from app list as it is automatic ...  it will show up whenever the count of the items in your applist is more than 40-45 apps and if u remove some apps it will automatically will be gone ...  so if you want to remove that jump list view u will have to uninstall some apps.

Comment: have u tried uninstalling APPs ..  if yes please tell the exact number after which it show up ??